# Question about Firebase Realtime Database security rules

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I'm implementing Firebase database to my Unity game and things are working great except I'm stuck on one little problem.

I'm making a weekly leaderboard system with a structure of Scores/YearWeek/Userid/Score where YearWeek is generated by the clients system, for example "202112". It's working but how do I set the rules for it so only authenticated owners can write their own scores?

Right now I have this which works if I would manually set the current week,

```
"Scores" :  {
"Week???" : {

  "$uid": {
  ".read": true,
  ".write": "auth.uid == $uid",
  ".indexOn" : "Score"
          }
}
}
```

but how could I write the rules so it applies to every child of Scores automatically as a new child is created each week? Something like;

```
"Scores" :  {
    "AnyChild" : {

      "$uid": {
      ".read": true,
      ".write": "auth.uid == $uid",
      ".indexOn" : "Score"
              }
    }
    }
```

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're already doing the exact same for `$uid`, which applies to any user.

Any rule starting with a `$` sign applies to all child nodes, unless a specific rules for that node name exists. So: `"$AnyChild"`

Also see the Firebase documentation on [wildcard capture variables](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/core-syntax#wildcard_capture_variables).

Comment: It worked, I was just wondering earlier what does the '$' mean haha. Thanks a lot! :)